# Binary to Decimal

Tags: number-systems, binary

Is it possible to convert a binary pattern to decimal pattern consists of 0's and 1's without loop (iterations).

Suppose if I have.

```
Binary Pattern          I need in Decimal
1                           1
10                          10
100                         100
```

I need it in c-programming, So binary pattern I have in integer (`int`).

```
Binary Pattern    number             I need in Decimal
1                  1       * 1                 1
10                 2       * 5                 10
100                4       * 25                100
1000               8       *                   1000

* means multiply
```

So what I need a mathematical equation that gives me  10<sup>(number-1)</sup>, without loop. This is power function actually but we don't have power operator in C language.

First, I don't know whether I am asking for impossible thing?

Comment: Are you allowed to convert the binary pattern to a string (array of characters)?

Comment: I need it in computer-programming

Comment: And you're not allowed to use a for or while loop? Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: @Adriano It will need a loop, I am looking for equation instead. Otherwise `power()` function I could have use. Yes I need equation for this particular pattern, I am not interested in   binary `1010` -- decimal `1010`

Comment: If $a_2=10000...00$ in base 2 with n trailing zeroes and $b_{10}=10000...00$ in base 10 then $b_{10} = a_2 5^n$

Comment: I suspect this question is more suited to Stack Overflow. Furthermore, if you explain *why* you don't want to use loops you may get better answers.

Comment: @BenMillwood its more mathematical question I think. I want an equation for this restrict problem domain. ---

Comment: I don't understand well what you want. What I understood is you are given a number, say $5$, in binary. This would be $101$. And you want to get the number in decimal notation that is written as $101$? Or do you want to get the 5 back? For the former you can just take $101$ and call it decimal from now on.

Comment: @RGB As I respond to Adrino, I am only interested in patterns that starts with `1` followed by `0`s for example `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`, I don't need `101` as input. -- What I wants if I have binary `100` that is actually `4` then I need `100` hundred, similarly if I have `1000` that is actually `8` then I need `1000` thousand. **---** After some comments and try I feel that what I need is not possible.

Comment: But **it is possible** and is described in my other comment. The factor is $5^n$.

Comment: @gammatester Can you post an answer with a more description, I will be so grateful.

Comment: I see. Then what you are looking for is to compute $\log_2(n)$ where $n$ is the input, and you are given always a power of $2$. Just to be clear. You are given the $8$ but you are not told this is $2^3$. Right? The number of zeros is not given, you have to compute it, isn't it?

Comment: @RGB Yes If I am given `8` then I need `1000`, but additionally I wants to convert without loop. (and a power function need a loop). Can we have some mathematical equation/function such that if `f(8)` == `1000` some liner equation? .... yet I think its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $m=2^n$, you are needing to compute $n$. You need to compute [binary logarithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Algorithm) I don't think you can compute it without a loop, unless your hardware has a function that essentially computes it. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_leading_zeros#Hardware_support) examples of functions that are equivalent and hardware supporting their computation.

The answer may also depend on how you actually store the input $m$. If it is written in memory in binary, you just need to print it. Whether this requires a loop or not depends on the language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I want to wait for few days before accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a non-zero integer number a which is assumed to be a power of 2, $a = 2^n$ (you can check this with `a & (a-1) == 0`), you can get the corressponding power of 10 with  `pow(10,floor(log(a)/log(2)+0.5)).`